# Pi Zero USB ethernet and USB mass storage

Tags: usb, ethernet, pi-zero

Idea:
Have the pi zero act as a USB mass storage device and to move files to a network location using ethernet. There are a few examples like this over wifi, example ([Smart flash drive](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive/)) but in my case I would need it work over ethernet.

If I solder on a male USB plug for mass storage and setup the device as g_mass_storage and g_ether [(g_multi)](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41) will the it still be able to communicate over a USB connected Ethernet cord?

To more be clear, would the having the USB bus act in slave(OTG) mode not let me communicate with a USB Ethernet port at the same time?

Comment: why do you think that wifi and ethernet transport LAN data differently? ..... it is unclear how you want to switch between the two USB modes?

Comment: I added a comment to try and make it more clear